# Random object generator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, random, fuzzing

I need a random object generator in JavaScript that generates a variety of objects with different fields and values. Any ideas where I can find such tool?

I need to generate random objects with various complexity.. My goal is to use JSON in order to serialize these objects and fuzz test my application http api.

Comment: Um... Write it? Or clarify your needs, because they sound very specific to me.

Comment: I need to generate random objects with various complexity.. My goal is to use JSON in order to serialize these objects and fuzz test my application http api.

Comment: See my answer, it does exactly what you said.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function createRandomObj(fieldCount, allowNested)
{
    var generatedObj = {};

    for(var i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++) {
        var generatedObjField;

        switch(randomInt(allowNested ? 6 : 5)) {

            case 0:
            generatedObjField = randomInt(1000);
            break;

            case 1:
            generatedObjField = Math.random();
            break;

            case 2:
            generatedObjField = Math.random() < 0.5 ? true : false;
            break;

            case 3:
            generatedObjField = randomString(randomInt(4) + 4);
            break;

            case 4:
            generatedObjField = null;
            break;

            case 5:
            generatedObjField = createRandomObj(fieldCount, allowNested);
            break;
        }
        generatedObj[randomString(8)] = generatedObjField;
    }
    return generatedObj;
}

// helper functions

function randomInt(rightBound)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * rightBound);
}

function randomString(size)
{
    var alphaChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var generatedString = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        generatedString += alphaChars[randomInt(alphaChars.length)];
    }

    return generatedString;
}
```

It will create a obj with X paramenters, all with a integer, float, string, boolean or null value.
I just made it :B

Comment: Will it work if I set the value for one field to be an object:

o[getRandomString(8)]=createRandomObj(5)

I want to get more complex object generated.. something like:

{"a":3,"b":{"c":4,"d":5}}

Comment: Oh, sure, I'll implement it in a moment :)

Comment: See second paramenter :), if it is true, it will make subobjects with using the same function and paramenters :)

Comment: Be careful with this - as far as i see, if fieldCount > 5 and allowNested = true, this will likely run forever at it may try to generate objects with infinite depth.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [hasard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hasard) library

> Random variables and random nested objects manipulation in javascript

```js
const h = require('hasard');

const randomInteger = h.integer({type: 'poisson', lambda: 4});

const randomString = h.string({
    size: h.add(randomInteger, 5),
    value: h.value('abcdefghijklmnopkrstuvw'.split(''))
});

const randomNumber = h.number([0, 100]);

const randomKeys = h.array({
    size: randomInteger,
    value: randomString
});

// we first define it, to use it as reference into randomObject
const randomValue = h.value();

const randomObject = h.object(
    randomKeys,
    randomValue
);

// And we set recursivity by setting his values afterward
randomValue.set([
    randomString,
    randomObject,
    randomNumber,
    randomInteger
]);
```

Results will looks like

```
[
  {
    "vbmujvv": "rfigcpcvpj",
    "sjmcgvvk": 3,
    "efdarehl": {
      "odinthsuca": "rwjhmbfus",
      "noihjtjen": 27.73332043042913,
      "brspkaagb": "lnuiabcfd"
    },
    "febtungjhfokf": 49.28625818957401,
    "eoemrkgi": {
      "jkcuwrpsh": "ekjoltm",
      "cincs": {
        "fcovbwk": {
          "whsgmjh": 48.00843935524626,
          "agsjflef": 46.700796253998014
        },
        "ovkdfudgfm": 84.83383163217746,
        "fpfetl": "djuvfjbjptf",
        "kobmkstj": {
          "wskgkkerk": 9,
          "kvnptptek": 37.63655947554132,
          "dsloun": 4
        }
      },
      "krirwk": {
        "sjgftomu": 51.663884142674775,
        "hpjgibnli": 4
      },
      "pkhkgruls": "isuodwjrg"
    },
    "ortomnue": 71.71303423929236
  }
]
```

*DISCLAIMER* i'm the author of [hasard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hasard) library

Comment: The recursive calls to `randomObject` in the `randomValue` can easily cause stack overflows. Something to be aware of, maybe fix with a max depth or something if possible. Nice library, thank you! :)