# What's the difference between angular.equals and _.isEqual?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, underscore.js

I mean is there any difference in performance? Which one is able to make the best deep comparison? Sometimes angular's equals function is not able to find every difference.

I have also noticed, that the angular version of this function is not checking the '$$hashKey' key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They basically act the same by comparing the values itself and all inner properties. Performance is also close to being the same, at least this will be a difference in 100-200 ms for 10000 elements. I have created small tests suite, **warning: your browser page will freeze for few seconds when you run code snippet**. I'm not totally sure is this correct way to measure performance so feel free to suggest better ways.

```js
angular
.module("comparsion", [])
.controller("ComparsionCtrl", function($scope) {
  var testCases = 10000;
  
  console.time("underscore");
  for(var i = 0; i < testCases; i++) {
    var obj = createRandomObj(5, true);
    var obj1 = createRandomObj(5, true);
    _.isEqual(obj, obj1);
  }
  console.timeEnd("underscore");
  
  console.time("angular");
  for(var i = 0; i < testCases; i++) {
    var obj = createRandomObj(5, true);
    var obj1 = createRandomObj(5, true);
    angular.equals(obj, obj1);
  }
  console.timeEnd("angular");
  
  // Random object generator from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443901/random-object-generator-in-javascript
  function createRandomObj(fieldCount, allowNested)
{
    var generatedObj = {};

    for(var i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++) {
        var generatedObjField;

        switch(randomInt(allowNested ? 6 : 5)) {

            case 0:
            generatedObjField = randomInt(1000);
            break;

            case 1:
            generatedObjField = Math.random();
            break;

            case 2:
            generatedObjField = Math.random() < 0.5 ? true : false;
            break;

            case 3:
            generatedObjField = randomString(randomInt(4) + 4);
            break;

            case 4:
            generatedObjField = null;
            break;

            case 5:
            generatedObjField = createRandomObj(fieldCount, allowNested);
            break;
        }
        generatedObj[randomString(8)] = generatedObjField;
    }
    return generatedObj;
}

// helper functions

function randomInt(rightBound)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * rightBound);
}

function randomString(size)
{
    var alphaChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var generatedString = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        generatedString += alphaChars[randomInt(alphaChars.length)];
    }

    return generatedString;
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="comparsion">
  <div ng-controller="ComparsionCtrl"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: And what would happen if the $$hashkey appears?

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice your last update. In this case correctly will be to use `angular.equals` because `underscore.isEqual` will fail `$$hashkey` comparison. Or you can use `angular.toJson` function to remove internal elements such as `$$hashkey`

Comment: You got downvoted before you've updated your question, it happens probably because people read your question like `_.isEqual vs angular.equals` as you can see from @Ashokreddy's answer but there also was a question about performance. Try to point out most important things first to prevent downvotes.

Comment: @konstantin-azizov, thanks so much for this answer. For those visiting stackoverflow using http**s** your code snippet needs to require underscore from http**s**://underscorejs.org instead of http or loading underscore will be blocked.

Comment: @JonLee-White, thanks for pointing out this issue, unfortunately, official site doesn't serve using a secure protocol, so I've used CloudFlare CDN.

Comment: @sztech, sort of, you can test it simply by replacing underscore with lodash CDN link in HTML script tag since they both have the same function

Answer (score 0):

angular.equals:this is angular equals comparision.

_.isEqual:this is underscore equal functionality.you need to import underscore js before using this.